# How to replace the specific digits of string into another value with conditions

Tags: r, replace, data.table

**Specify the number of digit is a must** ,and have to trigger this with condition

**Target :**
replace the 3rd place in a string to "4" with condition in TYPE "^JJ"

```
# DT
DT <- data.table(TYPE = c("AA","JJ","JJ","BB"),CODE = c("Y008h556","Y008j576","Y008l554","Y008z546")) 

# My attempt but not work
DT[grepl("^JJ",TYPE),CODE:=substring(CODE,3,3)<-"4"]
```

Do we have a simple way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you take it out of `data.table` syntax

```
substring(DT$CODE[grepl("^JJ",DT$TYPE)], 3, 3) <- "4"

DT
#   TYPE     CODE
#1:   AA Y008h556
#2:   JJ Y048j576
#3:   JJ Y048l554
#4:   BB Y008z546
```

I am not completely sure why it doesn't work in the `data.table` syntax but I think it is because we are doing `CODE:=substring <- ...`, whereas `substring` expects it to be in the form `substring <- ...`.

---

If we want to use `data.table` syntax, we can use `sub`

```
DT[grepl("^JJ",TYPE),CODE:=sub("(.{2}).", "\\14", CODE)]

DT
#   TYPE     CODE
#1:   AA Y008h556
#2:   JJ Y048j576
#3:   JJ Y048l554
#4:   BB Y008z546
```

---

As suggested in comments by @Frank and @chinsoon12, other ways to do it with `substring` are

```
DT[, CODE := {substring(CODE, 3, 3) <- "4"; CODE}]

DT[, CODE := `substring<-`(CODE, 3, 3, "4")]
```

Comment: keep in data.table syntax is the best and plain thankyou

Comment: Another way: `DT[, CODE := {substring(CODE, 3, 3) <- "4"; CODE}]`

Comment: and also: 'DT[, CODE := `substring<-`(CODE, 3, 3, "4")]'. note the backticks were eaten in this comment.

Comment: Frank , the expression is very new for me , awesome . **1--** Its a general syntax can be apply on another function as well ? Such as :  `DT[,COL := { function(COL ,arg)  ;  COL }] `  . **2 --** Does ` " <- " ` will pull down speed ?